# Wordress Custom post type shortcode always render as first element in Avada Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

In Avada Theme
I have created custom post type for slider, that is working on the backend module, I have already added a function for shortcode in functions.php, But when I render that shortcode in a page element like `[shortcode]` that always renders as first element, not at specific content part.

Can anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Please show your shortcode code in functions.php

Comment: A shortcode should only return the String/HTML, if you're using `echo` then it will cause the issue you're describing.